# Stock incoming char in loop function

Tags: c++, c, web-services, arduino

I'm working on arduino, and I want to stock some char which are incoming from a webservice.
The code will explain by itself :

```
void loop() {
   static int i = 0;
   static int count = 0;
   static char tmp[100];

   if (wifly.avaible()) {
      char c = wifly.read();
      Serial.print(c);
      tmp[i] = c;
      i++;
      if (c == '"')
         count++;
      if (count == 2)
      {
         Serial.print("Received : ");
         Serial.println(tmp);
      }
   }
}
```

If I let only this code :

```
void loop() {
   if (wifly.avaible()) {
      char c = wifly.read();
      Serial.print(c);
   }
}
```

All is working fine, all char are written. But i need to stock all incoming char for parse the whole string.

Have you an idea why, when I try to stock them, the program stop working and write nothing ?

Comment: buffer overflow once you get your 101th char, maybe ?

Comment: are you certain you will receive a maximum of 99 chars from the service? There is nothing in the code to guard against buffer overflow.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you need to reset `i` and `count` to 0 when you're done.

Comment: think he wants to save the values since he is using static.

Comment: I'd expect `Serial.println` to want a *null-terminated* string, unless the `char`s read include one that might be a reason for the program "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must protect against buffer overflow. The buffer `tmp` must be terminated with a zero value byte. `tmp` is static so is zero filled. Use a sentinel value (`BufferMaxChars`) to ensure that the final byte of the buffer is zero-value terminated.

I am guessing here - but possibly you want to print out the string value enclosed with quotes. If that is the case, the tmp buffer would only be assigned once count == 1 (when the first quote char was found).

```
void loop() {
   const int BufferMaxChars = 100-1;
   static int i = 0;
   static int count = 0;
   static char tmp[BufferMaxChars];

   if (wifly.avaible()) {
      char c = wifly.read();
      Serial.print(c);
      tmp[i] = c;
      i++;
      if (c == '"')
         count++;
      if (i >= BufferMaxChars || count == 2)
      {
         Serial.print("Received : ");
         Serial.println(tmp);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late approbation. But you was right and stupid I was... It was a buffer overflow. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad it's working now - we've all made similar mistakes!